# php save to csv file

Tags: php, post, csv

I'm wanting to store basic data from a single form box and I've created this php code base, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Can someone take a glance and see if anything stands out to why this wouldn't work.
**Edit: the csv file never updates with new data**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST["name"]; 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if (empty($name)) 
    { 
        echo "ERROR MESSAGE"; 
        die; 
    } 
    $cvsData ='"$name","$date"'.PHP_EOL; 
    $cvsData .= "\"$name\",\"$date\"".PHP_EOL; 
    $fp = fopen("emailAddressses.csv", "a");

    if ($fp) 
    { 
        fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file 
        fclose($fp); // Close the file 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'it doesn't seem to be working' mean? Does it do nothing? Something, but not what you expect?

Comment: Would be nice to know what "_doesn't seem to be working_" means. Error, empty file...?

Comment: Is there  any error ? Could you put 'error_reporting (E_ALL);' and recheck ?

Comment: Code seems fine if both `submit` & `name` are set, I'd recommend `fputscv`, but for anything more than _"it doesn't seem to be working"_ we need a more _exact_ error.

Comment: PHP has built-in CSV handling functions. Any reason why you aren't using them?

Comment: Looking at it, other than @Ibu's answer, I can't see any problem... Is your form sending the $_POST data? Is $fp open when you go to write? Try giving yourself a few echos to see if you're in the blocks you expect you're in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). This will add CSV to you file and take care of fields and line ends.

```
fputcsv($fp,array(array($name,$date)));
```

You can also specify delimiters and such if you want.

Comment: thanks I wasn't aware of fputcsv which is a much cleaner way to accomplish this task

Answer (score 7):

Use the nicer way in php : [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Otherwise you need to do lot of error handling to achieve in your case.

```
$list = array (
    array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'),
    array('Angelina ', 'Jolie', '37'),
    array('Tom', 'Cruise', '50')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I haven't started error trapping because I'm testing and not getting the file to submit was my first problem before hardening, but thanks I'm going down this route now.

Answer (score 0):

This part will not behave like you expect, the variables are not evaluated when inside single quotes:

```
$cvsData ='"$name","$date"'.PHP_EOL;
```

You will need to use double quotes:

```
$cvsData ="\"$name\",\"$date\"".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: it wasn't me, but since he's got two lines going into the CSV, with different quote styles, my guess is that he's aware of that and intending the first line (with the single quotes) to be a header line that has the variable name as headers. I agree it's not clear what the intention is, but it is clear from the two lines that he is aware of how quotes work.

Comment: @Spudley correct I'm going for headers in the csv, thanks though...I'm a JS guy still understanding the php syntax and usage