# PHP form to CSV file - that repeats

Tags: php, forms, csv

first of all I would like to let you know I know absolutely nothing about PHP, but I know a little HTML, which allows me to find this small PHP powered form around the web, Im trying to crate a form, where the submits are saved on to excel files or csv files. I'm currently using the following code

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $surame = $_POST["surname"];
        $home = $_POST["home"];

        if(empty($name)||empty($surame)||empty($home))
        {
            echo "ERROR MESSAGE";
            die;
        }
        $cvsData ='"Name","Surname","Home"'.PHP_EOL;
        $cvsData .= "\"$name\",\"$surame\",\"$home\"".PHP_EOL;
        $fp = fopen("test.csv", "a");

        if($fp)
        {
            fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file
            fclose($fp); // Close the file
        }


    }
    ?> 


 <form name="form" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
  Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /> <br />
  Home: <input type="text" name="home" /> <br /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

everything seem to be working fine, however every time I do a test, I'm also getting 
**Name Surname Home** above each data - can some one make it so  **Name Surname Home** only show on column 1, and following columns are the data?

Comment: By _not_ writing it into to file each and every time you add a new record …?

Comment: since your adding to an existing file, just create the file once with the line, then leave it out of the code completely

Comment: So I removed   $cvsData ='"Name","Surname","Home"'.PHP_EOL;

Comment: So I removed   $cvsData ='"Name","Surname","Home"'.PHP_EOL; and now its not repeating anymore :D --  but I would like it if I didnt have to edit the .cvs files...   how can I add array like it shows here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741664/php-save-to-csv-file